# What is the most efficient way to find bSmooth values in QS?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, number-theory, factoring

The heaviest part of QS is to search for bSmooth numbers.

So far I thought about two algorithms for solving this.

1. Trial division
2. - calculate $X$ as a product of all the values in the factor base
   - speed up the trial division with $gcd(X,Y)$ where $Y$ is a potential bSmooth value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient method is to use a *sieve*; this is why the method is called the quadratic *sieve*. It should be mentioned, though, that the sieve is just an optimization over [Dixon's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method), and doesn't affect the asymptotic running time apart from some (multiplicative) lower order terms. For a description of the sieve, you can start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Example_of_basic_sieve).

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what they describe in wiki. I understand how they contracted the v vectors out of the prime base in the range of 100. But I don't understand how it's been used latter.

Comment: There are many resources on the quadratic sieve other than Wikipedia. Perhaps some of them contain better descriptions.

Comment: I been reading more about this, and I understand now that by thieving you don't need to ask the question if a number is factor of $Y(x)$. By using your chosen bound you can find all the values that some prime $p$ is their factor. So unless I yet not understanding it all, you answer does not answering the question. Because even if I know that $p$ is a factor of some value $a$ I also need to check if $p^k$ is also a factor, if so I need to keep dividing, but this brings me to ground zero and back to the original question.